# Java, Apache Commons Configuration XML attributes

Tags: java, xml, apache-commons, apache-commons-config

I'm reading config from an XML file using Apache's commons.configuration. In one of the sections, I have several lines in the form of:

```
<bla attr1="something" attr2="something else" />
```

Ideally, I would like to do something like this:

```
List blas = config.getList("section.bla");
String attr1 = blas.get(0).getAttribute("attr1");
```

(The code above does *not* work, obviously)

Is this possible somehow, or do I have to query each attribute separately in the XPath-like notation, iterating myself through the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up manually iterating and querying for everything separately.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide-1.2/howto_xml.html

It would be something like this:

```
config.getString("bla(0)[@attr1]")
```